# Euler Polynomial Proof question

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, combinatorics

In a paper [here](http://pweb.nju.edu.cn/zwsun/BerE.pdf) on Bernoulli and Euler polynomials, the author presents a proof and i just have a question about the last two steps.  First, he defines the Euler Numbers recursively as
$$\sum_{k=0, 2|n-k}^n\binom{n}{k}E_k=0$$
and the Euler Polynomials as
$$E_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{E_k}{2^k}\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-k}$$
Then he goes to propose a lemma,

Let $n\in \mathbb{N}$, and let $\delta_{n,m}$ be 1 if $n=m$ and 0 if not.  Then
$$E_n(1)+E_n(0)=2\delta_{n,0}$$
And then the proof is as follows;
$$E_n(1)+E_n(0)=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{E_k}{2^k}\left(\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-k}+\left(0-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-k}\right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\sum_{k=0, 2|n-k}^{n}\binom{n}{k}E_k=2\delta_{n,0}$$

What are the justifications for the last two steps.  Taking the $2^{n-k}$ out, then clearly the powered terms are $0$ if 2 does not divide $n-k$ and $1$ otherwise, and the sum itself should equal 0 by the definition earlier.  Is the last step just reflecting the fact that when $n=0$, $E_0=1$ and $\frac{1}{2^{-1}}=2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly

$$\begin{align*}
\left(1-\frac12\right)^{n-k}+\left(0-\frac12\right)^{n-k}&=\left(\frac12\right)^{n-k}+\left(-\frac12\right)^{n-k}\\
&=\begin{cases}
\frac1{2^{n-k-1}},&\text{if }n-k\text{ is even}\\
0,&\text{if }n-k\text{ is odd}\;,
\end{cases}
\end{align*}$$

so

$$\frac{E_k}{2^k}\left(\left(1-\frac12\right)^{n-k}+\left(0-\frac12\right)^{n-k}\right)$$

is $\dfrac1{2^{n-1}}E_k$ when $n-k$ is even and $0$ otherwise. Thus,

$$E_n(1)+E_n(0)=\frac1{2^{n-1}}\sum_{k\ge 0\text{ and }2\mid n-k}\binom{n}kE_k\;.\tag{1}$$

(Note that it’s not necessary to specify an upper limit, since the binomial coefficient is $0$ if $k>n$.)

As you say, the summation on the righthand side of $(1)$ is $0$ for all $n\ge 1$, and for $n=0$ we do indeed use the fact that $E_0=1$ to get

$$E_0(1)+E_0(0)=\frac1{2^{-1}}\cdot1=2\;.$$

Comment: Thank you. I started to get it as I was typing the question up, so it was good to see the answer agree with my intuition.  Thank you.

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven: You’re welcome.